# Remove li if anchor within li is empty or javascript:;

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following:

```html
<ul>

  <li>
    <a href="https:www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="">No href defined, but attribute exists</a>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a>No href attribute</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">dead link</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do, is to check if an anchor has a valid href. From the above, if it has a link, that's fine, if it doesn't have a valid link (last three li's), then I want to remove its parent li's.

In essence, after my JQuery runs its checks, I should be left with the following markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https:www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
if($("ul li a").attr('href') === '' || $(this).text() === '') {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
}
```

But the above does nothing for me?

Answer (score 2):

## Remove anchors using selectors

A quick solution would be creating a comm separated list of query selectors:

- Start from every `li` (or a more specific selector) and use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- using the `[]` Attribute selector
- and the jQuery's [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- Use jQuery's `.closest("li")` to refer back to an ancestor element and `.remove()`

```js
$("li").find("a[href=''], a[href='javascript:;'], a:not([href])").closest('li').remove();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https:www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">No href defined, but attribute exists</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>No href attribute</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">dead link</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Remove Anchors using filter

For a more bulletproof solution using jQuery's [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
$("li").find("a").filter(function(i, a) {
  const href = a.getAttribute("href");
  return !href || /^javascript/.test(href);
}).closest('li').remove();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https:www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">No href defined, but attribute exists</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>No href attribute</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">dead link</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The same as above in pure **JavaScript** (without jQuery):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li a").forEach(a => {
  const href = a.getAttribute("href");
  if (!href || /^javascript/.test(href)) a.closest("li").remove();
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https:www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">No href defined, but attribute exists</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>No href attribute</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">dead link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `<a>` element has most of the same properties as `window.location` so you can filter the ones that don't have a `host` value or have empty attribute value

```js
$("li a").filter(function(){
  return !$(this).attr('href') || !this.host;
}).parent().remove()
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https:www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">No href defined, but attribute exists</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>No href attribute</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">dead link</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```